# Compilation error related to infile

Tags: c++, stream, file-io

I am not sure what the problem is exactly, but something that has to do with `infile` seems to be causing this? Any workaround for this? Do I have to download the latest version of mingw or something?

```
ifstream inFile("testdoc.txt");

std::ifstream currentDocument = infile;
```

> c:\qt\qt5.2.1\tools\mingw48_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.0\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h:786: error: 'std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)' is private
>        ios_base(const ios_base&);

Comment: You're trying to copy the file stream. Streams cannot be copied.

Comment: umm, i am running a file that someone gave me and apparently it's supposed to work. great, infile was passed as a reference in the function the second line is called.

Comment: also the errors doesn't point to that line of code.

Comment: `infile` may have been passed as a reference, but `ifstream f = infile` still attempts to copy-construct it. Also, the error doesn't point to that line because it's pointing to the private copy-constructors of `ios_base` and the stream buffer, the things which don't actually allow a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File streams don't allow copying. I guess you meant to use a reference:

```
std::ifstream& currentDocument = infile;
```

Though it's questionable why you need that line in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE -- Stream objects must never be copied or assigned to each other. 
>   There is the [reason](https://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/34-2.html), please read it!